# code for determinant of n X n matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I wrote my code and tried compiling in Codeblocks but it is not working. While running the programming it was showing errors in "int det(, )". I also tried using "*a" but it did not work. All it does is ask me the size of the matrix and the values and then stops. I am writing the full program but I believe the error is in the part of `int det(int n, int a[][])`.

```
#include<math.h>

main()

{

    int n,i,j;

    printf("enter the size of the matrix");

    scanf("%d", &n);


    int a[n][n];

    printf("enter the matrix \n");
   
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)

            {
                printf(" \n");

                scanf("%d",  &a[i][j]);
            }

    }

    printf("%d determinant is", det(a,n));

}

int det( int a[][n],int n)

{

    int i, j,k,d,l=0 ;

    if(n=2)
        
        {
            d = a[0][0]*a[1][1] - a[0][1]*a[1][0];
        
            return (d);
        
        }
    
    else
        
        for ( k = 0; k < n ; k++ )
    
        {
            int b[n-1][n-1];
            for (i=1; i<n; i++)
            
            {
            
                for(j=0 && j!=k ; j<n; j++)
                {
                    b[i][j]=a[i][j];
                }

            }

            l = a[0][j]*pow(-1,j)*det(b,n-1)+l;

        }

    return(l);

}
```

### Update:

Updated code:

```
    #include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int det( int n, int a[][n]);


int main(void)

{

    int n,i,j;

    printf("enter the size of the matrix ");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int a[n][n];

    printf("enter the matrix \n");

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)

            {
                printf(" ");

                scanf("%d",  &a[i][j]);
            }
      //  printf("\n");
    }

    printf(" determinant is %d\n", det(n,a));

}

int det( int n, int a[][n])

{

    int i, aj,bj,k,d,p=0 ;
    int sign =1;
    if(n==2)

        {
            d = a[0][0]*a[1][1] - a[0][1]*a[1][0];

            return d;

        }

    else

        for ( k = 0; k < n ; k++ )

        {
            int b[n-1][n-1];
            for (i=1; i<n; i++)

            {

                for(aj=0,bj=0 ; aj<n; aj++)
                {
                    if(aj==k) continue;
                    b[i-1][bj]=a[i][aj];
                    ++bj;
                }

            }

            p = a[0][aj]*pow(-1,k)*det(n-1, b)+p;
        }
    
    return p;

}
```

**[Edit by Spektre]**

You got wrong index in the last computation. I would change your `det` code to (summary of my comments):

```cpp
int det( int n, int a[][n])
    {   
    if(n<=0) return 0;                                 // stop recursion
    if(n==1) return a[0][0];                           // stop recursion
    if(n==2) return a[0][0]*a[1][1] - a[0][1]*a[1][0]; // stop recursion
    int i,aj,bj,k,p,sign,b[n-1][n-1];
    for (p=0,  sign=+1, k = 0; k < n ; k++, sign=-sign)
        {
        for (i=1; i<n; i++)
            {
            for (aj=0,bj=0 ; aj<n; aj++)
             if (aj!=k) 
                {
                b[i-1][bj]=a[i][aj];
                ++bj;
                }
            }
        p= p + (sign*a[0][k]*det(n-1, b)); // here you had aj instead of k causing problems !!!
        }
    return p;
    }
```

Sadly my compilers does not allow this kind of array passing and I would need to change it to either template or dynamic arrays which would be confusing for you ... So I tested on this and looks like it works:

```
const int N=3;
int A[N][N]=
    {
    { 1,2,3 },
    { 2,3,1 },
    { 3,1,2 },
    };
int det(const int n, int a[][n])
    {
    if(n<=0) return 0;                                 // stop recursion
    if(n==1) return a[0][0];                           // stop recursion
    if(n==2) return a[0][0]*a[1][1] - a[0][1]*a[1][0]; // stop recursion
    int i,aj,bj,k,p,sign,b[N][N];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) for (k=0;k<n;k++) b[i][k]=0;
    for (p=0, sign=+1, k = 0; k < n ; k++, sign=-sign)
        {
        for (i=1; i<n; i++)
            {
            for (aj=0,bj=0 ; aj<n; aj++)
             if (aj!=k)
                {
                b[i-1][bj]=a[i][aj];
                ++bj;
                }
            }
        p+= sign*a[0][k]*det(n-1,b); // here you had aj instead of k causing problems !!!
        }
    return p;
    }
```

with result `det(N,A)=-18` matching my own determinant functions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138446/discussion-on-question-by-manhattan-code-for-determinant-of-n-x-n-matrix).

Answer (score 3):

You need a function prototype for `det()` before `main()`, and the size argument needs to precede the VLA in the function call. Also, you should be using `size_t` for array indices instead of `int`.

There is no reason to use `pow()` to alternate signs; instead use `int sign = 1;` and multiply by `-1` when the sign needs to be alternated.

In the loop within `det()`, you have:

```
for(j=0 && j!=k ; j<n; j++) {}
```

with the intention of skipping over the `k`th column; instead you need to write this as:

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (j == k) continue;
    ...
}
```

But there is a further problem here with:

```
b[i][j]=a[i][j];
```

Since the indices for `b[][]` and `a[][]` are not the same, and in fact `b` is smaller than `a`, this will result in writing out of bounds to `b`. Instead you can declare separate column indices for the two matrices:

```
size_t aj, bj;
...
for (aj = 0, bj = 0; aj < n; aj++)
    {
        if (aj == k) continue;
            b[i-1][bj] = a[i][aj];
            ++bj;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Finally, you multiply the determinant of `b` by the wrong element of `a`:

```
l = a[0][j]*pow(-1,j)*det(b,n-1)+l;
```

After making the other corrections, this should be:

```
l = sign * a[0][k] * det(n-1, b) + l;
```

Here is the complete modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int det(size_t n, int a[n][n]);

int main(void)
{
    size_t n,i,j;

    printf("enter the size of the matrix: ");
    scanf("%zu", &n);

    int a[n][n];

    printf("enter the matrix: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",  &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("determinant is %d\n", det(n, a));

    return 0;
}

int det(size_t n, int a[][n])
{
    size_t i, aj, bj, k, d;
    int l = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    if(n == 2)
    {
        d = a[0][0] * a[1][1] - a[0][1] * a[1][0];

        return d;
    }

    else
        for (k = 0; k < n ; k++)
        {
            int b[n-1][n-1];

            for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (aj = 0, bj = 0; aj < n; aj++)
                {
                    if (aj == k) continue;
                    b[i-1][bj] = a[i][aj];
                    ++bj;
                }
            }

            l += sign * a[0][k] * det(n-1, b);
            sign *= -1;
        }

    return l;
}
```

Here are a couple of sample interactions:

```
λ> ./a.out 
enter the size of the matrix: 3
enter the matrix: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
determinant is 0

λ> ./a.out 
enter the size of the matrix: 3
enter the matrix: 
1 -2 3
4 -5 6
7 8 -9
determinant is 42
```

### Update

OP has posted updated code, and this update is to address the new issues. First, `main()` must (for the most part) have one of two function signatures:

```
int main(void);
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);  // equivalently int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Now, you must either move the definition of `det()` before `main()`, or add a function prototype:

```
int det( int n, int a[][n]);
```

Since `det()` uses VLAs, the size argument must come before the array argument, so the function calls must change to:

```
printf("%d determinant is", det(n, a));
```

and

```
p = a[0][k]*pow(-1,k)*det(n-1, b)+p;
```

Finally, within the inner loop in `det()`, you must keep two indices, `aj` and `bj`, since `a[][]` and `b[][]` are different sizes, and the elements of `a[][]` and `b[][]` do not exactly correspond:

```
for(aj=0, bj=0 ; aj<n; aj++)
{
    if(aj==k) continue;
    b[i-1][bj]=a[i][aj];
    ++bj;
}
```

I would suggest *not* using `pow()` for the sign alternation for a number of reasons; it involves an unnecessary library call, and the return value of `pow()` is `double`.

Most of these points were made in the original answer. After making these changes, your code worked for me.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking out time but Its still not working. What should be done, and can you tell me why there is a hold as I am new to this community.

Comment: The posted code works; before the change from `size_t` to `int` for the variable `l`, your `pow()` method would not work. BTW, this would need to be `pow(-1, k)`. You were using `j` here.

Comment: Thanks very much @David.
I am using Codeblocks to compile and code is not working in that.I also tried a couple of code running websites.

I changed size_t to int but even after that its not working. All it does is asks me the size of the matrix and thats it. 
Thankful that you are trying to help me out :)

Comment: I just edited as you had pointed out. with this it asks me the value of the matix elements but then stops

Comment: Thanks again. I did update my code in my original question on your lines but I did not change size_t, pow (although i changed j to k) and added continue statement. I also change variable l to p. Thanks a ton ...!!!

Comment: I saw your Ideone link. Thanks for that. You have been amazing in teaching me. Just one more thing. I am able to run my code but now it is not giving the right value of the determinant. I also plugged in a specific matrix instead of scanf( ) command but the result is not correct. I feel that there is some problem with 'aj' in 
"p = a[i][aj] .......* as the 'aj' considers the last value taken by variable 'aj' which happens to be 'n-1'. Can this be fixed some how.
It can be some other error as well. I am not getting the right answer. I have posted the updated code. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @manhattan-- you just need to change this line: `p = a[0][aj]*pow(-1,k)*det(n-1, b)+p;` to `p = a[0][k]*pow(-1,k)*det(n-1, b)+p;` This is because you need to multiply the sub-determinant by the `k`th element of `a[0]`. I had this in my original answer, but missed this change in the Update for your newer code, an also missed it in the Ideone code since it did not affect my test case! Just goes to show, you should always have more than one test case ;) Sorry about that; I will update that line in my answer.

Comment: Thanks......I should have pointed out myself....That was an easy one. Thanks again....

Comment: @manhattan-- Here is a new [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/TFY1oW). I see that you are still using `pow()` to alternate signs; as a next step, you should convert to using the multiplier `sign` instead. Also, if you found this answer helpful, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks very much. You were extremely helpful....Thanks again...